# Django translate

Tags: django, translate

I can't change language in template. In firebug i see that

```
<html lang="en">
```

wheh i click on Ukraine, language chang on `<html lang="uk">`

but, in template language don't changed. How i can fix this?

my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.i18n import set_language


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name='registration'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^i18n/setlang/$', csrf_exempt(set_language), name='set_language'),
]
```

my **index.html**

```
form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <li>
                <button type="submit"
                        name="language"
                        value="{{ language.code }}"
                        class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
                    {{ language.name_local }}
                </button>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in constant name, i had this

```
LOCAL_PATH = (
     'home/name/myapp/locale'
   )
```

and i change on this LOCALE_PATH**S** and all work fine.